# HTML5 video tag and RTP URL

Tags: html, video, rtp

I am looking to play out RTP-based audio and video streams in HTML5. I know the correct way to do this is using ConnectionPeer (HTML5) or PeerConnection (webRTC), but as neither are yet available, I am looking for alternatives.

One question sprung to mind for which I am looking for an answer.

- In the case of the video tag having the src set to `"rtp://127.0.0.1:4567/path/to/stream"`, what does the browser do with the RTP URL?
- Does it try to open a UDP connection to the server/port?

I am assuming the answer is no, and the request isn't converted into a HTTP request because it doesn't show up in my web server logs.

- Does the browser simply ignore it as RTP is not really a URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed `rtp://` schemas are not really a URL, because your player must know the streams/codecs/parameters for decoding it which are not carried over the RTP stream. Usually these parameters are in an accompanying SDP file.

If your browser does support RTP for HTML5 videos, try setting the `src` attribute URL to point to the  SDP file describing the streams (e.g., put the SDP file on an HTTP server and set the `src` attribute to point to it).